# Why is querySelectorAll not selecting my classes?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, dom-events, javascript-objects

I am trying to select six elements with the class name .hours but using document.querySelectorAll() isn't working and if I use document.querySelector() it returns only the first class with the name .hours, using document.getElementsByClassName() isn't working either. Please help :)

```js
const hoursTime = document.getElementsByClassName('hours');
const lastTime = document.querySelectorAll('.last-time');

hoursTime.onclick = function() {
    hoursTime.innerHTML = "Clicked";
}
```

```html
<div class="report_container">

      <div class="work_container">
        <div class="work">
          <div class="work_head">
            <h3>Work</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="work_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="play_container">
        <div class="play">
          <div class="play_head">
            <h3>Play</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="play_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="study_container">
        <div class="study">
          <div class="study_head">
            <h3>Study</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="study_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="exercise_container">
        <div class="exercise">
          <div class="exercise_head">
            <h3>Exercise</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="exercise_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social_container">
        <div class="social">
          <div class="social_head">
            <h3>Social</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="social_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="self_care_container">
        <div class="self_care">
          <div class="self_care_head">
            <h3>Self Care</h3>
            <img src="/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" class="elips" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="self_care_content">
            <h1 class="hours">0hrs</h1>
            <p class="last-time">Select TIme Tracking</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll` both return an array. You can't just apply `onclick` to your array. You need to apply it to each element _inside_ that array. In other words: Iterate over the array. `for(let i = 0; i < hoursTime.length; i++){ hoursTime[i].onclick = ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what you did wrong, you first need to learn what a [Javascript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is. You most likely already know what a variable is:

```js
var foo = 1;

console.log(foo); // returns "1"
```

An array is like a collection of variables:

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(foo); // returns "array (1, 2, 3)"
console.log(foo[0]); // returns "1"
console.log(foo[1]); // returns "2"
```

As you probably also already know, computers start counting at 0 whereas humans start counting at 1. So to get first value out of the array `foo`, you want to call the key 0 `foo[0]`.

Arrays use a unique key (index) for each value (element). To get the value, you use the key.

Now lets look at your code:

```js
const hoursTime = document.getElementsByClassName('hours');
```

This would return:

```
hoursTime = [Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element]
```

If you try to apply `onclick` on `hoursTime`, you end up doing:

```
Array.onclick();
```

Obviously Javascript doesn't understand that. You can't click on arrays. However, you can click on elements! But, as explained above, you need to get those elements out of that array.

You could technically do that manually:

```js
hoursTime[0].onclick = function();
hoursTime[1].onclick = function();
```

Obviously that's pretty inconvenient. It requires writing a lot of code while you want to put the same function on each Element inside the array.

That's where loops come in. A loop simply goes over each value inside the array. There are several ways to do that. One would be to count the length of the array and loop over it:

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];

// Start at 0, check if the number is still smaller than the length of the array and if so, run the code and add a number
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++){
    console.log(foo[i]); // First returns 0, then 1, then 2
}
```

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is another way of looping through an array. The difference is that you do not have to count the length of the array yourself. This gives you less control over the loop. Like with the method above, you could skip one number if you wanted to. With `forEach` you can't do that.

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];

foo.forEach(function(element, index){
    console.log("Found value: "+element+" at key(index): "+index);
});
```

So to make your code work, you need to loop over your array and apply the onclick event to each of the elements inside it:

```js
const hoursTime = document.getElementsByClassName('hours');

for(let i = 0; i < hoursTime.length; i++){
    hoursTime[i].onclick = function();
}

// or

hoursTime.forEach(function(element){
    element.onclick = function();
});
```

Comment: You just broke this down for me. I no understand it really good. You are the best :)

Comment: @AbdulhameedMustapha You're welcome. I honestly recommend that you spend some time on [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/). It's 100% free, interactive frontend development learning, with no advertisements. And it has a very active community who are open to beginners and help them to learn. Up to you of course, just pointing it out as you seem eager to learn and don't just want others to do your job for you.

Comment: I'd sure do. Thank you @icecub

Answer (score 0):

Actually `querySelectorAll` selects correctly elements and returns a NodeList (array of elements)

If you want to add an event to an array of elements you have to use a `loop`. You can use `forEach` for example

```
function fn() {
    this.innerHTML = 'clicked'
}
document.querySelectorAll('.hours').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', fn))
```

Comment: OP does not "have" to use `forEach`. It's just one option. Also, please explain _what OP did wrong_ in your answer so OP (and other future readers) can _learn_ something from your answer. Other than that, also explain _what exactly your code does_. OP most likely doesn't know what `forEach` actually does, let along what `event.addEventListener` does.

Comment: @icecub yes, I am beginner javascript programmer. I'd really appreciate if you explain to me more. And I know what event.addEventListener does

Comment: @AbdulhameedMustapha I always prefer `addEventListener` because with that we can attach multiple onclick-events but with `onclick` you can attach only one event handler,